# cfp and agedb dataset test

Tags: python, face

I'm working on a face recognition project based on face image reconstruction recently. I want to test my model on the ageDB dataset and CFP dataset, but I can't find their test codes on the Internet. Can you provide them?I'll be grateful to you

ageDB dataset and CFP dataset test code